# TaskCompletionSource for better scalability?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Just trying to understand why SleepAsyncB not uses thread:

> The SleepAsyncA method uses a thread from the thread pool while
>   sleeping. The sec- ond method, however, which has a completely
>   different implementation, does not occupy a  thread while waiting for
>   the timer to run. The second method gives you scalability.

I suppose method SleepAsyncB creates Timer via Win API and gives callback. But I suppose Timer itself is separate thread?

```
public static Task SleepAsyncA(int millisecondsTimeout)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout);

            });
        }

        public static Task SleepAsyncB(int millisecondsTimeout)
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;
            var t = new Timer(delegate { tcs.TrySetResult(true); }, null, -1, -1);
            tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(t);
            t.Change(millisecondsTimeout, -1);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
```

Comment: Is this from a book? I'd have used (and awaited) Task.Delay ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx => See Figure 5

Comment: Regarding your question: SleepAsyncA is blocking a TP Thread for the entirety of its runtime. SleepAsyncB does not because Timer can use native functionality that does not need an actual Thread to be blocked. _"But I suppose Timer itself is separate thread?"_ - No, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

`SleepAsyncA` will force a Thread from the TPL ThreadPool to Sleep for the duration of `millisecondsTimeout`, effectively rendering that Thread unusable.

`SleepAsyncB`, by using a Timer, is delaying a piece of code to be executed later, rather than blocking a thread until `millisecondsTimeout` elapses. This does not use a Thread, because this is a native functionality, provided by the OS.

Also, as @Fildor has already stated in the comments, `SleepAsyncB` code could be replaced by a single call to `Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout)` (Assuming that Timer is `System.Threading.Timer`)

Comment: I think the confusion is because OP thinks `Timer` would need a Tread internally - which of course is not correct.

Comment: This might not be obvious to everyone, and also, i think there is a Thread (managed by the CLR) that is responsible to loop through a TimerQueue and dispatch all elapsed Timers to a ThreadPool, but this thread is always there, and you are not effectively using or blocking it (although your statement that _"Timer itself is not a separate thread"_ might be considered truthy)

Comment: That's what I wanted to say.